# com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.exception.NotFoundException: Page not found

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, sites-9.5

We are using dxa 2.2 java with Tridion sites 9.5
While fetching a published page we are getting below error

```
10:12:00.167 [ajp-nio-172.31.50.0-9014-exec-7] ERROR c.s.d.m.c.c.CommonsPageController - Page not found: /index
com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.exception.NotFoundException: Page not found: /index
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.getPageModel(PageController.java:308)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(PageController.java:123)
    at com.sdl.dxa.modules.commons.controller.CommonsPageController.handleGetIndexPage(CommonsPageController.java:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.PageNotFoundException: Unable to load page, by request PageRequestDto(publicationId=8, pageId=0, path=/index, uriType=tcm, includePages=INCLUDE, contentType=MODEL, dataModelType=R2, expansionDepth=100, depthCounter=DepthCounter(counter=100, unlimited=false))
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.graphql.GraphQLProvider.loadPage(GraphQLProvider.java:110)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.GraphQLContentProvider.loadPage(GraphQLContentProvider.java:179)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.AbstractContentProvider.getPageModel(AbstractContentProvider.java:70)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor248.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.getPageModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.getPageModel(PageController.java:305)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.sdl.dxa.api.datamodel.model.PageModelData` out of NOT_AVAILABLE token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1445)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1219)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1171)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:198)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4189)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2476)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:2929)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.graphql.GraphQLProvider.mapToType(GraphQLProvider.java:165)
    at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.graphql.GraphQLProvider.loadPage(GraphQLProvider.java:101)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. :-)  But what is the question, exactly? And what did you already analyze yourself?

Comment: I can see your error message you have used the custom controller "CommonsPageController", it seems like you have missed to handleNotFoundException the page not found error exception handling for the 404 page. refer to DXA framework PageController code for the reference https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-java/blob/fab57d17e81574bf59bba76be1f8a636a404b038/dxa-framework/dxa-common-api/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/common/controller/PageController.java#L225

Comment: @Velmurugan but the page is published and I can see it in the broker database "Page" Table. Please see https://ibb.co/svBPZgq

Comment: Using fiddler try to capture the graphiql query and double-check the parameter values is that all going correctly?